# scala - Can I overload curried methods?

Tags: scala

Is there a way to overload methods in Scala that take multiple parameter lists? E.g. I'd like to do this:

```
def foo(a: Int)(b: Int)(c: Int): Int

def foo(a: Int)(b: Int): Int
```

I can define it like this, but trying to call the second method like this:

```
foo(1)(1)
```

makes the compiler complain about "ambiguous reference to overloaded definition", which seems justified. Is there a way to achieve something like this? The last parameter might be considered optional in some cases, for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use overloading for this, since due to the currying there would be two `foo` methods differing only in their return type.

You can use Scala 2.8's [optional and named parameters](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2075) to approximate this, but you'd have to call the method as `foo(1)(1)()`. E.g.,

```
object Hello {
  def foo(a : String = "Hello,") : String = a

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(foo() + foo(" world!"))
  }
}
```