# Can implicits be used to disambiguate overloaded definition?

Tags: scala, implicit, overload-resolution

Consider the following overloaded definition of method `mean`:

```
def mean[T](data: Iterable[T])(implicit number: Fractional[T]): T = {
  import number._
  val sum = data.foldLeft(zero)(plus)
  div(sum, fromInt(data.size))
}

def mean[T](data: Iterable[T])(implicit number: Integral[T]): Double = {
  import number._
  val sum = data.foldLeft(zero)(plus)
  sum.toDouble / data.size
}
```

I would like second definition which returns `Double` only to be used in the case of `Integral` types, however

```
mean(List(1,2,3,4))
```

results in compiler error

```
Error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method mean in class A$A16 of type [T](data: Iterable[T])(implicit number: Integral[T])Double
and  method mean in class A$A16 of type [T](data: Iterable[T])(implicit number: Fractional[T])T
match argument types (List[Int])
mean(List(1,2,3,4))
^
```

Is there any way to use the fact that `Fractional[Int]` implicit is not available in order to disambiguate the two overloads?

Comment: Can not test right now, but have you tried adding the **Dummy** _implicit_? - Other option would be to create your own typeclass that generalizes over both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala - Can I overload curried methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268876/scala-can-i-overload-curried-methods)

Comment: I suggest using a typeclass for this - this is proven working method for such situations.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez [`Dummy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745066/dummyimplicits-is-this-used-and-how) did not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala only considers the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179229/scala-currying-and-overloading) argument list for the *overload* resolution, according to the [specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution). Both `mean` methods are deemed equally specific and ambiguous.

But for implicit resolution the implicits in scope are also considered, so a workaround could be to use a magnet pattern or a type class. Here is an example using the magnet pattern, which I believe is simpler:

```
def mean[T](data: MeanMagnet[T]): data.Out = data.mean

sealed trait MeanMagnet[T] {
  type Out
  def mean: Out
}

object MeanMagnet {
  import language.implicitConversions

  type Aux[T, O] = MeanMagnet[T] { type Out = O }

  implicit def fromFractional[T](
    data: Iterable[T]
  )(
    implicit number: Fractional[T]
  ): MeanMagnet.Aux[T, T] = new MeanMagnet[T] {
    override type Out = T

    override def mean: Out = {
      import number._
      val sum = data.foldLeft(zero)(plus)
      div(sum, fromInt(data.size))
    }
  }

  implicit def fromIntegral[T](
    data: Iterable[T]
  )(
    implicit number: Integral[T]
  ): MeanMagnet.Aux[T, Double] = new MeanMagnet[T] {
    override type Out = Double

    override def mean: Out = {
      import number._
      val sum = data.foldLeft(zero)(plus)
      sum.toDouble / data.size
    }
  }
}
```

With this definition it works normally:

```
scala> mean(List(1,2,3,4))
res0: Double = 2.5

scala> mean(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0))
res1: Double = 2.5

scala> mean(List(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f))
res2: Float = 2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at typeclass solution as suggested by others

```
trait Mean[In, Out] {
  def apply(xs: Iterable[In]): Out
}

object Mean {
  def mean[In, Out](xs: Iterable[In])(implicit ev: Mean[In, Out]): Out = ev(xs)

  private def meanFractional[T](data: Iterable[T])(implicit number: Fractional[T]): T = {
    import number._
    val sum = data.foldLeft(zero)(plus)
    div(sum, fromInt(data.size))
  }

  private def meanIntegral[T](data: Iterable[T])(implicit number: Integral[T]): Double = {
    import number._
    val sum = data.foldLeft(zero)(plus)
    sum.toDouble / data.size
  }

  implicit val meanBigInt: Mean[BigInt, Double] = meanIntegral _
  implicit val meanInt: Mean[Int, Double] = meanIntegral _
  implicit val meanShort: Mean[Short, Double] = meanIntegral _
  implicit val meanByte: Mean[Byte, Double] = meanIntegral _
  implicit val meanChar: Mean[Char, Double] = meanIntegral _
  implicit val meanLong: Mean[Long, Double] = meanIntegral _
  implicit val meanFloat: Mean[Float, Float] = meanFractional _
  implicit val meanDouble: Mean[Double, Double] = meanFractional _
  import scala.math.BigDecimal
  implicit val meanBigDecimal: Mean[BigDecimal, BigDecimal] = meanFractional _
}

object MeanTypeclassExample extends App {
  import Mean._
  println(mean(List(1,2,3,4)))
  println(mean(List(1d,2d,3d,4d)))
  println(mean(List(1f,2f,3f,4f)))
}
```

which outputs

```
2.5
2.5
2.5
```